# How do I inflate a View with custom attribute values?

Tags: android, android-view, android-attributes

How do I set values in my `View` programmatically that it can use in `onCreate()`? Attributes can only be set in XML and member values can only be set after the `View` is inflated (and `onCreate()` already called).

Do I need to call the `View` constructor and set member values before inflating it? Or is there a better way?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, here, or what exactly the restrictions are. Why can't you initialize the `View` per usual? That is, why can't you just inflate it, or instantiate it, and then immediately set its properties as needed?

Comment: @MikeM. I'm trying to inflate a View from XML and then set some attributes programmatically *before* onCreate() is called. Is that possible?

Comment: Not really. Well, not particularly elegantly, anyway, as far as I can figure. Why must the attributes be set before `onCreate()`? That's basically where you're meant to get the UI set up before it's displayed. `View`s aren't actually measured and laid out until after `onCreate()` finishes.

Answer (score 0):

If you inflate the view using `Context.getLayoutInflater().createView()`, you can pass custom attributes to this view programatically, using the last parameter

**EDIT**

In order to use attributes both from the xml and programatically, you will have to implement a custom LayoutInflater. However, since

You can see an example of custom layout [In Android Rec Library](https://androidreclib.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/custom-layoutinflater/).

You can see an example of custom AttributeSet in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29028227/558668).

**Custom AttriuteSet**

If I combine all those answer, you will get what you want, but it will require some boilerplate code, since `AttributeSet` is not really suitable for adding params on the fly. So you will have to implement `AttributeSet` (which is an interface) that gets the original `AttributeSet` in the constructor, and wraps all its functionality, and return the correct values for the parameters you want to add programatically.

Then you will be able to do something like:

```
private static class MyLayoutInflater implements LayoutInflater.Factory {

        private LayoutInflater other;

        MyLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater other) {
            this.other = other;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            if (name.equals("MyView")) {
                attrs = MyAttributeSet(attrs);
            }
            try {
                return other.createView(name, "", attrs);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }

    private static class MyAttributeSet implements AttributeSet {

        private AttributeSet other;

        MyAttributeSet(AttributeSet other) {
            this.other = other;
        }

        < More implementations ...>
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new MyLayoutInflater(getLayoutInflater());
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(...)
    }
```

It may work, but there is probably a better way to achieve what you want.

**Add Custom Params**

You can implement a custom layoutinflater that will set some parameters before returning the view, so those will be added before `onCreate` is called on the view. So it will be something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new LayoutInflater.Factory() {
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            if (name.equals("MyView")) {
                View myView = myView(context, attrs); // To get properties from attrs
                myView.setCustomParams(SomeCustomParam);
                return myView;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to inflate the View from XML, which contains additional attributes.

Comment: So for that you will need a custom `LayoutInflater`. I will edit my answer